# as3-xmp-file library to work with PNG images

Tags: actionscript-3, image, apache-flex, metadata, xmp

The example stated in  [as3-xmp-file](http://code.google.com/p/as3-xmp-file/) is working with a .JPG format file.
I tried to change the test.jpg to an test.png file. But it does not seems to update the title up into the the .png file.

Anyone have any ideas how can this be done?

Code from as3-xmp-file website

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  import de.qwesda.as3_xmp_file.as3_xmp_file;
  import com.adobe.xmp.*;

  private function init():void {
    var file1:as3_xmp_file = new as3_xmp_file(File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/test.jpg");

    if(file1.file.exists){
      trace(file1.xmp.dumpObject());

      var dc_exif:Namespace = XMPConst.dc;

      file1.xmp.dc_exif::title = "Title";

      file1.save();
    }

    var file2:as3_xmp_file = new as3_xmp_file(File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/test.jpg");

    if(file2.file.exists){
      trace(file2.xmp.dumpObject());
    }
  }
]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: To my knowledge PNG doesn't contain XMP data

Comment: What about getting the metadata out from png?

Comment: Base on [ADOBE XMP PDF](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:2FWHuN4uTPQJ:xml.coverpages.org/XMP-Embedding.pdf+XMPEmbedding.pdf&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi26BeqENcInTnYwfH1sSg-GItTKUW3p1XFTfgkff7eZSccmJ36_CgAtrHrYsOpq94QoQpEyiO3PUstIR0jShZgD63z-IHIW-WY-AHBlO3qfkbewfltirm-534HsQlLHHmGZkJY&sig=AHIEtbSjbJq5N2a5jkMaOaWjil2i71HZEQ) on page 4 it states that An XML packet can be embedded in a PNG graphic ﬁle by adding a chunk of type “tXMP”.
The data of the chunk should be a UTF-8 serialized XML packet.

Comment: tXMP data is not XMP data actually I have no idea what it is but I would not rely on that info being a stanard that all PNGs will use. JPEG XMP data contains camera data and other things that the PNG won't.

Comment: hi,just found this out from wikipedia [XMP wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) and it says XMP can be used in several file formats such as PDF, JPEG, JPEG 2000, JPEG XR, GIF, PNG, HTML, TIFF, Adobe Illustrator, PSD, MP3, MP4, Audio Video Interleave, WAV, RF64, Audio Interchange File Format, PostScript, Encapsulated PostScript, and proposed for DjVu. In a typical edited JPEG file, XMP information is typically included alongside Exif and IPTC Information Interchange Model data.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a answer for this library to write the code back in, but i subsitute it by using the code given from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466335/metadata-of-png-file-format)