# MetaData of PNG File Format

Tags: actionscript-3, image, apache-flex, png, metadata

I tried to convert the PNG file into bytes wit the code below

```
var enc:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();    
enc.encodeBytes(bytes);
var base64data:String = enc.drain();
trace("base64data : "+base64data);
trace("end of base64data ");
```

But what i get is a chunk of characters like this

> AKGt1qPxYT9Aduzcags+mgc1fp8SPIDQLEB4zwMxOoieCCCJdsICQBAIiwBi5Ra8hnfACt+YHnro
>   waV23Dwp5y+YyxBCp+4SNOwGCD0sfq0+gKgVyw6A0EM5/KCm2Y0dO7cpS5cuVubMeUGZNv15dnjX
>   3LkvKqtWr1De2L+XLRpo8cAWFaFFBgACgAAgAAgA0hEgbOi8be7DGYBcv3FdeXbsM7Y8Pyury7+N

How can i display the data of the PNG file format properly?

Comment: Which Base64Encoder are you using?

Comment: Look around line 105 for the metadata part specifically, but found this general (de|en)coder http://wonderfl.net/c/oVSK

Answer (score 0):

Answer is provided by  shaunhusain with the [link here](http://wonderfl.net/c/oVSK)